# RegEx get string after specific character unless specific character doesn't exist

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I have two separate strings:

- This is a test string
- This: is a test string

How would I create a regular expression which:

1. If a ":" exists, then get everything after the ":" and a space.
2. If a ":" does NOT exist, then get the whole string.

For example, the regular expression should do the following:

- This is a test string > This is a test string
- This: is a test string > is a test string

Comment: try `((?<=:)((.)+))|\b[a-zA-z0-9\t\n\v\f\r ]+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^([^:\n]+)$|^[^:\n]*:(.*$)
```

You can use this.Grab the `capture` or `group`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/9

If you want to match an `empty string` too use

```
^([^:\n]*)$|^[^:\n]*:(.*$)
```

Comment: I think your first `+` should be a `*`. The empty string is not an exception in the OP's rules, it's a valid string that does not contain `:`, so should be matched.